# Forming differential equations:

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Form the differential equation from the following equation:
> $$xy=Ae^x+Be^{-x}+x^2$$

My attempt:$$xy=Ae^x+Be^{-x}+x^2\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
Differentiating both sides w.r.t. x$$xy'+y=Ae^x-Be^{-x}+2x\tag{2}\label{eq2}$$
Again differentiating w.r.t. x$$xy''+2y'=Ae^x+Be^{-x}+2\tag{3}\label{eq3}$$
Adding equation (1) and (2),
$$xy'+y+xy=2Ae^x+x^2+2x\\
\implies Ae^x=\frac{1}{2}(xy'+y+xy-x^2-2x)$$
Subtracting equation (2) from equation (3),
$$xy''+2y'-xy'-y=2Be^{-x}+2-2x\\
\implies Be^{-x}=\frac{1}{2}(xy''+2y'-xy'-y-2+2x)$$
Substituting the values of $Ae^x$ and $Be^{-x}$,
$$xy=xy''+2y'+x^2-2\\
\implies xy''+2y'-xy+x^2-2=0$$
But, in my book the answer is:
$$xy''+2y'-xy=0$$
Please check where is my mistake

Comment: 8th equation does not follow from your work. Sign error on $2x$

Comment: Substitution in the final step looks suspicious to me

Comment: @DavidPeterson After fixing the sign error on 2x it still seems wrong. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28xy%27%27%2B2y%27-xy%27-y-2%2B2x%29%2F2%2B%28xy%27%2Bxy%2By-x%5E2-2x%29%2F2

Comment: You can avoid a lot of calculations in detecting that the terms with $A$ and $B$ are in the same combination in (1) and (3), so that you can get the result directly as difference (3)-(1).

Comment: @LutzLehmann Oh right! I didn't think about it. It's a short method. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$xy=Ae^x+Be^{-x}+x^2$$
For the homogeneous differential equation we have:
$$ \implies r^2-1=0$$
$$(xy)''-xy=0$$
$$(y'x+y)'-xy=0$$
$$xy''+2y'-xy=0$$
This is what you have. And it's also the book's answer. For the inhomogeneous DE:
$$(xy)_p=x^2$$
$$(xy)_p''-(xy)_p=2-x^2$$
So that the DE is:
$$xy''+2y'-xy=2-x^2$$

Comment: Wow, nice explanation . Thank you

Comment: @AnkitaPal you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting equation (2) from equation (3),
$$xy''+2y'-xy'-y=2Be^{-x}+2-2x\\
\implies Be^{-x}=\frac{1}{2}(xy''+2y'-xy'-y-2-2x)$$
should instead be:
$$xy''+2y'-xy'-y=2Be^{-x}+2-2x\\
\implies Be^{-x}=\frac{1}{2}(xy''+2y'-xy'-y-2+2x)$$

But the rest follows as you wrote exactly, and your solution is correct.

Comment: Sorry it was my typing error, but in my copy I did it +2x. Please check the calculation 

Comment: @AnkitaPal I inputted your book's solution into Wolfram Alpha and it doesn't seem to agree with the equation in the problem. Look at the solution WA gives: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=xy%27%27%2B2y%27%3Dxy

Comment: @Divide1918 Ok, then then there is mistake in the book. Thank you for this confirmation 

Comment: Yes, I agree too. The book has a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is actually correct. It's the book that has made a mistake.

Alternate solution: Let $xy-x^2=u(x)$, then $u=Ae^x+Be^{-x}$. We can form the equation $u''=u$, which is equivalent to $xy-x^2=\dfrac d{dx}(xy'+ y-2x)=xy''+2y'-2$, or $xy''-xy+2y'+x^2-2=0$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you for driving this